# How to cluster different texts from different files?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dbscan, tfidfvectorizer

I would like to cluster texts from different files to their topics. I am using the 20 newsgroup dataset. So there are different categories and I would like to cluster the texts to these categories with DBSCAN. My problem is how to do this?

At the moment I am saving each text of a file in a dict as a string. Then,  I am removing several characters and words and extracting nouns from each dict entry. Then, I would like to apply Tf-idf on each dict entry which works but how can I pass this to DBSCAN to cluster this in categories?

my text processing and data handling:

```
counter = 0
dic = {}
for i in range(len(categories)):
            path = Path('dataset/20news/%s/' % categories[i])
            print("Getting files from: %s" %path)
            files = os.listdir(path)
            for f in files:
                with open(path/f, 'r',encoding = "latin1") as file:
                    data = file.read()
                    dic[counter] = data
                    counter += 1
```

```
if preprocess == True:
        print("processing Data...")
        content = preprocessText(data)
if get_nouns == True:
        content = nounExtractor(content)
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words=stop_words, max_features=max_features)
for i in range(len(content)):
        content[i] = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(content[i])
```

So I would like to pass each text to DBSCAN and I think it would be wrong to put all texts in one string because then there is no way to assign labels to it, am I right?

I hope my explanation is not too confusing.

Best regards!

EDIT:

```
 for f in files:
                with open(path/f, 'r',encoding = "latin1") as file:
                    data = file.read()
                    all_text.append(data)
```

```
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words=stop_words, max_features=max_features)
    tfidf_vectorizer.fit(all_text)
    text_vectors = [] 
    for text in all_text: 
        text_vectors.append(tfidf_vectorizer.transform(text))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should fit the TFIDF vectorizer to the whole training text corpus, and then create a vector representation for each text/document on it's own by transforming it using the TFIDF, you should then apply clustering to those vector representation for the documents.

**EDIT**

A simply edit to your original code would be instead of the following loop

```
for i in range(len(content)):
        content[i] = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(content[i])
```

You could do this

```
transformed_contents = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(content)
```

`transformed_contents` will then contain the vectors that you should run your clustering algorithm against.

Comment: Ok so you mean I pass each text to the vectorizer like vectorizer.fit_transform(texts[1])? But how should I save it to be able to pass it to my clustering method?

Comment: No, first you concatenate all you text in a variable, let's call it all_text, then call vectorizer.fit(all_text). Afterwards, for each text you call text_vector[i] = vectorizer.transform(text[i]). Thus creating a vector representation for each text that you can use for clustering

Comment: So you mean like I have done before just with a list like data = file.read() all_text.append(data). And then fit that which will be the text_vetor, right? and then load each text in again and apply the text_vector with vectorizer.transform()? Am I understanding it right?

Comment: After having all the data in all_text you should do the following 

vectorizer.fit(all_text) 

Then loop over the text again, transforming and saving the transformations into their own array as follows : 
text_vectors = [] 
for text in all_text_list:
     text_vectors.append(vectorizer.transform(text))

this text_vectors variable is the one you should use for clustering.

Comment: I am getting this error: ValueError: Iterable over raw text documents expected, string object received. I have added my actual code to Edit in my original post.

Comment: Then the same error occures there. The previous error was thrown here:         text_vectors.append(tfidf_vectorizer.transform(text))

Comment: then just simply wrap text in a list as follows 

text_vectors.append(tfidf_vectorizer.transform([text]))

Comment: Now it works thank you! But dbscan wont take it. I guess it has something to do that it is a list? Because it says: "Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample."

Comment: I think this might be due to the text_vectors being a list instead of a np.array, could you try and check my updated answer above, it should work.

Comment: This does not work, maybe because content is a dict? And if I try to convert the text_vectors to an np.array and pass this array to dbscan it throws this error: ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Comment: Oh yes, content should be a list. retry and let me know.

Comment: Ok now I got this: ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 1353]. I am a little bit confused right now because I do not understand why it creates only 1, 1353 ...